# What determines on when Wordpress loads an archive template or page template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am rewriting the URLs for a custom post type.

```
// Add rewrite rule
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
            '^movies/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
            'index.php?post_type=movies&movie_id=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Full code available in this thread regarding another issue: [WordPress - request post by url with custom field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546742/wordpress-request-post-by-url-with-custom-field-value/40549441#40549441)

However the above code only sends me to the archive.php page.

URL example: example.com/movies/157336/
The ID is a custom field, and not the actual post ID.

When I rewrite the URL to `index.php?post_type=movies&movie_id=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]` then wordpress loads the single.php

Yes I have read through https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ however it does not mention anything about what is required to request the single.php or archive.php page.

From trial and error it seems when the GET parameters `p` or `name` are available, then WordPress loads the single.php, otherwise it loads archive.php

I want wordpress to load the single.php or in this case single-movies.php and not archive.php
How can I tell wordpress to do that?

Comment: you have to pass the permalink() of post to href, wordpress redirect to archive page if it is category page. @Kevin M

Comment: @Parth Mahida I don't fully understand. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: For every post there is a permalink, you can see it under the post title while you are editing it. this permalink is for single post, use it whenever you wants to go to single.php file @KevinM

Comment: @Parth Mahida Ah now I understand. No that is not the problem. The permalink is properly set in the admin panel and when I click on it, it sends me to the archive page, that is why I am asking, how does Wordpress determine when it loads the archive.php page and single.php. So far it seems when the `p` or `name` parameter in the URL are missing, then it loads the archive.php